# Could not find gem 'tzinfo-data x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im super new to rails development and am following a basic rails tutorial to get started. I have successfully install rails and ruby on my windows 10, but for some reason the server does not work. I have tried different versions of rails and every time I get a different error. Here is the error message I keep receiving. Any help will be extremely be appreciated. Thank you.

$ rails s

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:396:in `block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!': Could not find gem 'tzinfo-data x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:366:in`each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:366:in `verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:212:in`start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:191:in `resolve'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:235:in`resolve'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:218:in`specs_for'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:207:in `requested_specs'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:109:in`block in definition_method'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:21:in `setup'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler.rb:101:in`setup'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in`require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in`require'
        from C:/Sites/myarticles/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in`require_relative'
        from bin/rails:3:in `'

Here is the Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
# gem 'rack-cors'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: please share you Gemfile

Answer (score 3):

Please do following, but share Gemfile also, as error message is saying Gem not found.

First install ssl_certificate into your ssl_certificate directory of railsinstller. You can following [this url](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88#manual-solution-to-ssl-issue)
Now use following command to update

```
gem update --system
```

Now go to your rails project folder and run following command

```
bundle install
```

Also check you have installed node, npm and yarn. If still error persist make sure all installation of node done.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with you, when I need to run

```
rails s
```

The alert was coming like

```
Could not find gem 'tzinfo-data'
```

The default on my Gemfile

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I remove "platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]", then my Gemfile like this

```
gem "tzinfo-data"
```

After that run

```
bundle install
```

It's work on my Windows 10